# Best way to communicate the status of long running PHP-script to other PHP-Script for SSE

Tags: php, server-sent-events

I have a long running PHP-Script, which handles a big XML-file.

1. user does XML upload to upload.php
2. upload.php running few minutes
3. Browser creates new EventSource("status.php") to ask the current status

So what is the best practised way to let status.php know what upload.php is doing?

Plan was to write a log-file in upload.php and let status.php look if something new is inside the log-file.

But for sure there is other ways to let upload.php and status.php communicate together, or not?

Comment: basically do you want to track the upload of that xml file?

Comment: Not the upload, but this xml is 1.1GB of data. It transforms into flatfile with little bit data conversion. I want to let the use know about the conversion progress and then when result is ready for download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I usually do is create a database table that holds records representing the file uploads, and return references to those records (I like to use a GUID token and not just the auto-incrementing ID) to the client upon the initial file upload requests. The client then polls a service that accepts the identifier as a parameter, verifies that the record belongs to the user, then returns the details. The process that handles the file import updates the record as needed. Once the record indicates completion or failure, the client can redirect to wherever they should go after the import completes or fails. Update the "notes" field with diagnostic details, exceptions, etc. on failure.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `file_imports` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `file_name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    `status` enum('Pending','Processing','Success','Failed') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Pending',
    `notes` longtext,
    `create_date` datetime NOT NULL,
    `complete_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `token` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY (`token`),
    KEY `file_imports_user_fk` (`user_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `file_imports_user_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: Ok, so you use a database table to read the current status. That's a better solution than just put into a txt-file...